# JSON pretty print

Tags: python, python-2.x, json, formatting

Here is my simple program to pretty print a JSON object. I'm looking for advice of better pretty print solutions, functional bugs, code style and algorithm time/space complexity improvements.

BTW, I have fixed all PEP8 issues I met with using Pycharm auto-annotation feature, there are some alerts on PEP8 which I think is either minor or a bit too much overhead to this program (e.g. using `isinstance` other than `==`). But if I am reading or judge it wrong, appreciate to point out.

```
import json

def print_pretty(source, prefix, level):
    if not source:
        return
    if type(source) == type({}):
        for k,v in source.items():
            for i in range(level):
                prefix.append('\t')
            prefix.append(k)
            if type(v) != type({}) and type(v) != type([]):
                prefix.append(' : ' + str(v))
            prefix.append('\n')
            if type(v) == type({}) or type(v) == type([]):
                print_pretty(v, prefix, level+1)
    elif type(source) == type([]):
        print_pretty('[', prefix, level)
        for i in source:
            print_pretty(i, prefix, level+1)
        print_pretty(']', prefix, level)
    else:
        for i in range(level):
            prefix.append('\t')
        prefix.append(str(source))
        prefix.append('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    json_string = '''{

    "stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "othertype": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    },
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing": [[1,42],[2,2]]
     }
}
    '''
    result = []
    print_pretty(json.loads(json_string), result, 0)
    print ''.join(result)
```

Comment: If you're worried about the overhead of a function call (have you tested that, by the way?), why use e.g. `type({})` rather than `dict`? Also, what functionality does this add over the built-in `pprint`?

Comment: Nice catch @jonrsharpe, and vote up. It is why we always need cross code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linter alerts on using `isinstance` rather than comparing types with `==` are pretty strong and should not be considered minor: what if I have a `Counter` and I want to examine it's content using your function… Well… it'll be of no use since `type(Counter())` is `Counter` and not `dict`. So trying to pretty print it will enter the `else` part of your code and I won't have anything more than a regular `print`, how disapointing…

However, `Counter` being a subclass of `dict`, `isinstance(Counter(), dict)` returns `True`, so if you had used that, I would at least have had each key-value pairs on their own lines.

Better, yet, as [duck-typing](/questions/tagged/duck-typing) is the norm in Python, would be to not test anything and try to:

1. call the `items` method and format at a dictionnary; or, if it fails,
2. transform to an iterator using `iter` and format as a list; or, if it fails,
3. format as a single value.

Using proper `try: ... except:` clauses, it allows for large reusability.

---

Now for your function’s behaviour: instead of checking the type of the values in a dictionnary, you can just call your function recursivelly, it will be checked there. This will mean that you will need to change the formatting to add `':'` for collections as you do for simple values. But I do think it's an improvement as it will explicit what are keys and what are values, rather than simple elements of an iterable.

To continue on the "explicit is better than implicit" way, I think that removing the `{` and `}` delimiters for dictionary-like objects is a bad choice: it allows you to "write" the first element without offset; and to add one only for the content of containers.

And lastly, using a function named `print_pretty`, I expect it to `print` the representation of whatever it is called with, rather than returning to me an incomplete intermediate representation; that I have to `join` and `print` myself. Better call that function `generate_pretty` (and, oh, turn it into a generator rather than returning a list) and provide a `print_pretty` that will `print ''.join(generate_pretty(…)`; or maybe a little bit more, see the following rewrite:

```
def generate_pretty(source, level):
    try:
        mapping_items = source.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:  # Not a dict
        if isinstance(source, basestring):
            # Need to check for strings there because
            # strings and single characters are iterables
            # so the `try: iter(..); else: ...` would
            # result in an infinite recursion
            yield source
        else:
            try:
                sequence_items = iter(source)
            except TypeError:  # Not a sequence
                yield str(source)
            else:  # Indeed a sequence
                yield '[\n'
                for element in sequence_items:
                    yield '\t' * (level + 1)
                    for line in generate_pretty(element, level + 1):
                        yield line
                    yield ',\n'
                yield '\t' * level
                yield ']'
    else:  # Indeed a dict
        yield '{\n'
        for key, value in mapping_items:
            yield '\t' * (level + 1)
            yield str(key)
            yield ': '
            for line in generate_pretty(value, level + 1):
                yield line
            yield ',\n'
        yield '\t' * level
        yield '}'


def format_pretty(source):
    return ''.join(generate_pretty(source, 0))


def print_pretty(source, filename=None):
    formatted = format_pretty(source)
    if filename is None:
        print formatted
    else:
        with open(filename) as f:
            f.write(formatted)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json

    json_string = '''{

    "stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "othertype": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    },
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing": [[1,42],[2,2]]
     }
}
    '''
    print_pretty(json.loads(json_string))
```

---

That being said, the organisation now match more closely what is available in the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module. That offers even more customization. So basically, `print_pretty` could be just:

```
from pprint import pprint as print_pretty
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, tried your code and your code, and your code always run without completion? I am using Python 2.7 + Pycharm on OSX.

Comment: Another comment is, I am developer from Java and C++ in the past, it seems it is not a good practice to use exception to control program flow, you are using exception to control flow, is it good practice and recommended way in Python 2.7? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa exceptions are pretty friendly in python, in fact, the `for` loop uses one hunder the hood to stop iteration. You may way to read about [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) in python and the `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Mathias, mark your reply as answer. Always enjoy reading your posts.